# Cast NSManagedObject subclass to protocol

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have a managed object subclass named Tag that has a to-many relationship to another managed object subclass Card; in my code I retrieve a Tag from the store, and then access the associated Card objects and add them to an array.  I also have another managed object subclass CardVariation that is added to the array.

Both Card and CardVariation conform to a TaggedCard protocol; when I access the objects stored in the array, I cast them to the TaggedCard protocol:

```
id<TaggedCard> x = (id<TaggedCard>)[theArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

I then attempt to send a TaggedCard message to the object:

```
NSString *y = [x taggedCardName];
```

When this runs, I get an exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[NSManagedObject taggedCardName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e7c620'
```

I can cast my object to a Card (or CardVariation) with no problem; is there something special with casting a managed object subclass to a protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like x isn't an instance of the class you're expecting. The cast avoids a compiler warning, but if the instance x were to respond to taggedCardName, your code would work regardless.

What's the output of this?

```
NSLog(@"%@", [x class]);
```

If you don't get the class you're expecting (e.g. `<Card: 0x4e72090> (entity: Card; ...)`, you have an instance of the wrong class. Here are two things to check:

1. Make sure your subclass .m files and your data model are listed in Build Phases > Compile Sources for your target.
2. In the data model, under the entity, make sure your subclass is listed as the Class, and not NSManagedObject.

Comment: `<NSManagedObject: 0x4e72090> (entity: Card; id: 0x4e5a590 <x-coredata://B59F7E07-B27A-48F6-A508-480DDFCC93D5/Card/p23> ; data: <fault>)`

Comment: Sorry, that was the object x; the class is NSManagedObject

Comment: Yeah – that's what's wrong. You should be seeing `<Card: 0x4e72090> (entity: Card; ...)`.

Comment: Are your subclass .m files and your data model listed in Build Phases > Compile Sources for your target?

Comment: Hmm. In the data model, under the entity, is your subclass listed as the Class, or does it say NSManagedObject?

Comment: Awesome, that was it - for some reason the class was set to NSManagedObject; correcting it to Card fixed it - thanks